# How to keep the villagers out of your house in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is my house.

[image]

Due to the improved design, my house is much better illuminated than the surrounding houses, what causes most of the villagers to pack inside. Since I didn't like it, I have started using iron doors to keep them out. The problem, however, is that I get stuck quite often. Now, I'm looking for a different way to keep the villagers away while I can still use normal spurce wooden doors. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: place your doors inverted, also keeps zombies out :)

Comment: Inverted?  Not sure what you mean?

Comment: That's a big village you bult.

Comment: I used iron doors and pressure plates on both sides to solve this problem. I just built a small porch onto the front of my house. :)

Comment: try using a fence around the house with a fence gate- villagers cant open fence gates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of facing straight on to the doorway while placing the door, stand off to the side. You'll know you've done it right if the door places in an open position instead of a closed position. This will make it so when the door is "open" it will actually be closed, and when it is "closed" it will actually be open. This will confuse the villagers to the point that they will be unable to open the doors to get into your house.

Comment: I've tried ut, but the villagers still enter. The only difference is that now they do it during the day. Also, they have trouble getting out.

Comment: This did work for me in 1.16, but jobless villagers still tried to path toward the job site blocks on the other side of the door(s), crowding around the door.

Answer (score 5):

Use a fence gate or iron door instead of a regular wooden door.  Villagers can only open standard wooden doors.

Another option would be to build a small patio or deck in front of your house, and use the trapdoors as your decking.  The trick is to have your house 1 block above the surrounding area, place down a block in front of your door, put a trapdoor on top of that. You can remove the block below.  A player can jump up onto the trapdoor, but a villager generally won't or can't jump onto anything higher then 1 block.

Answer (score 1):

Build a fancy 2x2 or 3x3 redstone piston door.

**Advantages:**

- Villagers won't recognise your house if you don't have wooden door.
- As villagers don't flick levers or buttons they won't enter your house

Answer (score -3):

Build steps leading to your house. Like a porch. They don't go up steps.

Comment: Villagers will use stairs. You could probably use a ladder though (technically villagers *can* use ladders, they just usually don't)